# $(x,y) = (u,v) \implies x = u \wedge y = v$ using Hausdorff's definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, set-theory

I have been asked to solve this problem.

> $(x,y) = (u,v) \implies x = u \wedge y = v$. Solve using this ordered pair definition: $\Delta \neq \square \Rightarrow(x, y)=\{\{x, \Delta\},\{y, \square\}\}$.

I have investigated a little bit and discovered this is Hausdorff's definition usually stated as:

$$(a,b)=\{\{a,1\},\{b,2\}\}.$$

> > Theorem 1. $\{x,y\}=\{u,v\}\implies (x=u\wedge y=v)\vee (x=v\wedge y=u)$.

This is my try:

Considering the definition,
$$(x,y)=(u,v)\implies \{\{x,\Delta\},\{y,\square\}\} =\{\{u,\Delta\},\{v,\square\}\}.$$

By theorem 1, we know

$$\underbrace{\left[\left(\{x,\Delta\}=\{u,\Delta\}\right)\wedge \left(\{y,\square\}=\{v,\square\}\right)\right]}_{(1)}\vee \underbrace{\left[\left(\{x,\Delta\}=\{v,\square\}\right)\wedge\left( \{y,\square\}=\{u,\Delta\}\right)\right]}_{(2)}.$$

Case (1): $\left(\{x,\Delta\}=\{u,\Delta\}\right)\wedge \left(\{y,\square\}=\{v,\square\}\right)$. Applying theorem 1 again, we have:
$$\left[(x=u\wedge \Delta=\Delta)\vee (x=\Delta \wedge \Delta=u)\right]\wedge\left[(y=v\wedge \square=\square)\vee (y=\square\wedge \square=v)\right].$$

Case (2): $\left(\{x,\Delta\}=\{v,\square\}\right)\wedge\left( \{y,\square\}=\{u,\Delta\}\right)$. Applying theorem 1 again, we have:

$$\left[(x=v\wedge \Delta=\square)\vee (x=\square \wedge \Delta=v)\right]\wedge\left[(y=u\wedge \square=\Delta)\vee (y=\Delta\wedge \square=u)\right].$$

I am not sure how to finish this proof. It does not make sense at all, what do you think?

Comment: You can simplify by getting rid of cases where $\Delta=\square$. Then do more case distinctions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\Delta=\Delta$ and $\square=\square$ are true, we can use transitivity of $=$ to simplify case (1) to
$$\left[(x=u)\vee (x=u=\Delta)\right]\wedge\left[(y=v)\vee (y=v=\square)\right].$$
The first term tells you $x=u$ in both cases and the second term tells you $y=v$ in both cases.

Since $\Delta=\square$ is false, case (2) simplifies to
$$\left[x=\square \wedge \Delta=v\right]\wedge\left[y=\Delta\wedge \square=u\right].$$
So in this case $x=\square=u$ and $y=\Delta=v$.